# .Copy method fails when worksheet not selected

Tags: vba, excel

This is part of my script, easy loop copying some rows from one sheet to another:

```
a = 3
With Sheets("ATD")
    Do While .Range("A" & a) <> ""
        If .Cells(a, 6).Value = "x" And .Cells(a, 8).Value = "y" Then
            .Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a, 10)).Copy
            Sheets("ART").Range("A" & Sheets("ART").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        a = a + 1
    Loop
End With
```

It fails **almost** every time on `.Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a, 10)).Copy` line (*Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error)*. When I add `.Select` command like this:

```
a = 3
    With Sheets("ATD")
        Do While .Range("A" & a) <> ""
            If .Cells(a, 6).Value = "x" And .Cells(a, 8).Value = "y" Then
                .Select
                .Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a, 10)).Copy
                Sheets("ART").Range("A" & Sheets("ART").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
            a = a + 1
        Loop
    End With
```

everything works fine.

I know I can change `.Copy` on something like

`Sheets("ATD").Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a, 10)).Value = Sheets("ART").Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 10)).Value`

but I have another question. If `.Copy` function require, that cells I want to copy are in currently selected sheet, or am I missing something here?

Comment: `Cells(col,row)` is really `[ActiveSheet.]Cells(col,row)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
.Range(.Cells(a, 1), .Cells(a, 10)).Copy
```

The points are really important, as they reference the current `Cells` with the `Sheet` Object set in the `With Sheets("ATD")` line.

Comment: I knew I forgot something, than you very much.

Comment: Welcome :) This thing with the "." is really a nightmare, because sometimes it works without them and sometimes not.